# Navigation Highlighting with 2 Pages from the Same Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Following a previous post I (almost) successfully implemented highlighted navigation using CSS and Rails.

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "sweets" %>"><%= link_to 'Sweets', sweets_path %>           </li>
        <li class="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "sweets/new" %>"><%= link_to 'New Sweets', new_sweets_path %>     </li>
        <li class="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "tasks" %>"><%= link_to 'Tasks', tasks_path %>         </li>'Customers', customers_path %> </li>
        <li class="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "suppliers" %>"><%= link_to 'Suppliers', suppliers_path %> </li>   
</ul>
```

The only issue is that one of my navigational items is for creating a new item rather than being to an entirely different page. I have tried the above using /new on the end of the normal controller text but it hasn't worked.

Is this method possible when navigating to the method pages or do I need to implement it in a different way? Sorry if this is a repeat question but I couldn't find anyone with the same situation.

Thanks in advance and any hints or tips are always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for action as well:

```
if params[:action] == 'some_action'
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Coupled with the previous controller params it worked perfectly.
"<%= "active" if params[:action] == "new" &&  params[:controller] == "sweets"%>"